How to connect to an local server from production server
I have configured a server for (FrontEnd) Flutter application and successfully deployed it to my VPS, but I can't communicate with my (Backend) server (Maybe because it still uses HTTP instead of HTTPS to communicate with it) I can access it on the internet using http:// myip:3000 but I can't access it through my flutter app
this is my serverside code i use elysia js
const app = new Elysia()
 .use(cors())
 .onError(({code, error}) => {
 if(code == "NOT_FOUND" || error === new NotFoundError()){
 return Response.json({"message" : "Page not found"})
 }
 })
 .get("/projects", projectsView)
 .get("/projects/:id", projectDetailView, {params : t.Object({id: t.String()})})
 .post("/contact", createContactFormsView, {
 body : t.Object({
 name : t.String(),
 email : t.String(),
 message : t.String(),
 company : t.String(),
 phoneNumber : t.String(),
 }
 )})
 .get("/images/:id", async ({params :{id}}) => {
 if(existsSync(assetsFolder + "/" + id)){
 return Bun.file(assetsFolder + "/" + id)
 }
 return Response.json({
 "message": "Not Found"
 },{status: 404})
 })
 .listen({
 hostname : "0.0.0.0",
 port: 3000,
 development : process.env.PRODUCTION === "true"? true : false,
 });

more on that my FrontEnd server already used SSL and verified by Sectigo
and this is my NGINX sites-enabled and sites-available configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name justportofolio.xyz;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name             justportofolio.xyz;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/justportofolio.xyz.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/justportofolio.xyz.key;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        root                    /var/www/html/web;
    index           index.html index.htm;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                #proxy_pass https://$host:8000;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }

    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

}

on my Flutter side i've tried http://localhost:3000 , http://my_vps_ip:3000
do i really need to buy a new domain and ssl cert for my backend? my Website is just about my portofolio
